# asp:ScriptManager render bundles first

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundle, scriptmanager

Is anyone knows the way by set the **ScriptManager.Scripts** render before the `ScriptManager.CompositeScript.Scripts` render in DOM ?

Scripts have been added to that control's collections by c# code.

Comment: Microsoft gives an overview here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398863(v=vs.100).aspx